# laravel 4 - Route::controller - unused parameters

Tags: php, laravel-4, routes, http-status-code-404

I have this route in a laravel 4 app:

```
Route::controller('about','AboutController');
```

When I go to `http://website/about/imprint` I get the imprint, but when I go to `http://website/about/imprint/12345` , (which is not used in the controller) I get the imprint as well. It does not throw an error.

Is this a problem? Should I somehow catch it and show a 404 error, or does it not matter?

I can even go to `http://website/about/imprint/7/7/7/7` for example, without getting an error message.

the `AboutController` looks so:

```
<?php
class AboutController extends BaseController
{
    public function getIndex()
    {
        return View::make('about');
    }

    public function getImprint()
    {
        return View::make('imprint');
    }

    public function getDatenschutz()
    {
        return View::make('datenschutz');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use something like this for my routes:

> Route::get('/about/imprint', 'AboutController@getImprint')

But that is just my opinion. With this syntax, it automatically gives the NotFoundHTTPException for something like this '/about/imprint/7/7/7/7/7/7/7' so you don't have to check for it.

Now if you want extra stuff, you could have a different route for that such as:

> Route::get('/about/imprint/{id}', 'AboutController@getImprint')->where('id', '[0-9]+');

Then getImprint() would look like this:

```
function getImprint($id){
    // can only get here if id is a number (based on where clause)
}
```

Comment: You are right. The automatic 404 is good. I tried to keep my routes.php small with `Route::controller()` and now recognized, that this does not throw the Exception. (found a link on google to website/user-xy/posts/23 which did not exist anymore, but did not give a 404 error and tried to show the website/user-xy/posts view)

Comment: I can never seem to get my routes.php file as small as I would like to haha. You could get the current URL and ***explode()*** it. If there is more information than what you want, throw a 404.

Comment: Perhaps checking if `Request::segment(2)` is set could also work (?). But I don`t know if it is necessary (or good practise).

Comment: You could check if segment(3) is set (about/imprint/[3]). If it is, go somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Anything after `imprint/` is being passed into your `getImprint()` function as arguments. You can see this by changing your getImprint() function to print out the arguments, like so:

```
public function getImprint() {
    return "Imprint <br />Args: " . print_r(func_get_args(), true);
}
```

Then `http://website/about/imprint/12345` would return a page that looks like this:

```
Imprint 
Args: Array ( [0] => 12345 )
```

and `http://website/about/imprint/7/8/9/10` would return a page that looks like this:

```
Imprint 
Args: Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 8 [2] => 9 [3] => 10 )
```

Comment: Okay. And should I show a 404-error or do a redirect when somebody goes to imprint/12345 or does it not matter? I mean for search engines  or security, for example.

Comment: As long as you're not using the arguments for anything, I don't see any security issues. Also, I assume most visitors to the imprint page would be arriving there through a navigation link on your site that points to `imprint/`, so I doubt you'll see traffic to `imprint/anything/else`.


If you wanted to redirect to 404 when arguments were passed you could just redirect when `empty(func_get_args()) == true`, but I think leaving it as-is is more user friendly.